# How to call "componentDidMount" or equivalent on every route change?

Tags: javascript, react-native, navigation

At the moment I am trying to call `componentDidMount` on every time I try to hit a new route. but when I change route and then go back to the original component it doesn't call `cdm` again.

is there any way to do this?

can post code if necessary but I just want to know how to call something on every route change as historically I would use `componentDidMount`

this is for react native `navigation` by the way as I know this way works in normal React

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe to the focus event of react navigation and do whatever you need to do when the relevant route is navigated to.

Documentation of how to subscribe can be found in the react navigation api reference:

- https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-events.html
- https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue to this recently. In my case, I think the issue mostly revolved around mounting components with React Native's stack navigation. componentDidMount will only be called once while you are on the stack, and won't re-render until you leave the stack and return to it. I put how I approached fixing the issue below:

```
 /** 
  * @issue page does not refresh if its already been mounted on the navigation stack
  * @todo  listen to navigation events, and trigger refresh
  * @todo  get rid of componentDidMount, and instead 
  *        have the navigation event handler trigger the refresh
```

So basically, instead of using `componenDidMount()`, when you navigate to the given page, pass some type of navigation param that lets the page know it needs to update.

`navigate('ExamplePage', { example: '<new Example>' })}`

and on `ExamplePage`

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  if (nextProps.navigation.state.params.example) {
    this.props.retrieveData(this.props.example);
  }
}
```

**EDIT/UPDATE**
As another option, and a much better solution in my opinion, you can listen to NavigationEvents. Here is the documentation, though it doesn't go very in depth
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-events.html

So in my case I would still listen to the navigation parameters passed in from `navigate` on the previous screen. Then by adding this code below, I add my refresh function to `onDidFocus`, which will be triggered every time the page appears on the screen.

`import {NavigationEvents} from 'react-navigation';`

```
   render() {
     return (
       ...
       <NavigationEvents onDidFocus={() => this._refresh()} />
       ...
     )
   }
```

With this solution, you can also still call `componentDidMount()` initially. And you don't have to use `componentWillReceiveProps` as that's a bad practice